# Can not connect to AWS Amplify PubSub -> Socket error:undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-iot, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I've been trying out all ways to get the **Amplify/PubSub** working without any luck. It seems all the documentation are rather outdated.

Here is what I have done so far. Please note all hashes are made up ;-)

1. Created a fresh React Native app
2. Installed amplify packages
3. Installed Amplify CLI
4. Invoked `$ amplify configure`
5. Invoked `$ amplify init`
6. Invoked `$ amplify add auth`
7. Invoked `$ amplify push`, which created the `aws-exports.js` object
8. Created a super simple component

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { View } from 'react-native';

    import { withAuthenticator } from 'aws-amplify-react-native';
    import Amplify, { Auth, PubSub } from 'aws-amplify';
    import { AWSIoTProvider } from '@aws-amplify/pubsub/lib/Providers';

    import awsmobile from './aws-exports';

    Amplify.configure({
      Auth: {
        mandatorySignIn: true,
        region: awsmobile.aws_cognito_region,
        userPoolId: awsmobile.aws_user_pools_id,
        identityPoolId: awsmobile.aws_cognito_identity_pool_id,
        userPoolWebClientId: awsmobile.aws_user_pools_web_client_id,
      },
      Analytics: {
        disabled: true,
      },
    });

    Amplify.addPluggable(
      new AWSIoTProvider({
        aws_pubsub_region: 'ap-southeast-2',
        aws_pubsub_endpoint:
      'wss://a123456789d-ats.iot.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt',
      })
    );

    Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG';

    class App extends PureComponent {
      componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.authState === 'signedIn') {
          Auth.currentCredentials().then((creds) => {

            // get the principal that needs to be attached to policy
            console.log('principal to be attached', creds.identityId)

            PubSub.subscribe('topic_1').subscribe({
              next: (data) => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)),
              error: (msg) => console.log('ERROR: ', msg.error),
              close: () => console.log('Done'),
            });
          });
        }
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <View/>
        );
      }
    }

    export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

9. I attached AWS root certificate to my iPhone (see below)

[image]

10.Create a IAM policy for AWS IoT

- `IoTAppPolicy`
- `iot:*`
- `arn:aws:iot:ap-southeast-2:1234567890:*`

11.Attach the principal I got from `Auth.currentCredentials` to the policy

```
aws iot attach-principal-policy --policy-name IoTAppPolicy --principal ap-southeast-2:db1234bc-5678-90123-4567-89ae0e123b4
```

12.Attach Policies to `Auth Role`

- `AWSIoTDataAccess`
- `AWSIoTConfigAccess`

Yet, when I run the app I get the following error log

```
[DEBUG] 51:42.745 SignIn - Sign In for test@test.com
[DEBUG] 51:44.616 AuthClass CognitoUserSession {idToken: CognitoIdToken, refreshToken: CognitoRefreshToken, accessToken: CognitoAccessToken, clockDrift: 0}
[DEBUG] 51:44.616 Credentials - set credentials from session
[DEBUG] 51:46.247 Credentials - Load credentials successfully 
[DEBUG] 51:46.248 AuthClass - succeed to get cognito credentials 
DEBUG] 51:47.150 Hub - Dispatching to auth with  {event: "signIn", data: CognitoUser, message: "A user 2d...de has been signed in"}
[DEBUG] 51:47.151 SignIn CognitoUser {username: "2d...de", pool: CognitoUserPool, Session: null, client: Client, signInUserSession: CognitoUserSession, …}
[DEBUG] 51:47.152 AuthClass - Getting the session from this user: CognitoUser {username: "2d...de", pool: CognitoUserPool, Session: null, client: Client, signInUserSession: CognitoUserSession, …}
[DEBUG] 51:47.152 AuthClass - Succeed to get the user session CognitoUserSession {idToken: CognitoIdToken, refreshToken: CognitoRefreshToken, accessToken: CognitoAccessToken, clockDrift: 1}
[DEBUG] 51:47.574 AuthPiece - verified user attributes {verified: {…}, unverified: {…}}
[INFO] 51:47.575 Authenticator - Inside handleStateChange method current authState: signIn
[DEBUG] 51:47.575 VerifyContact - no unverified contact
[INFO] 51:47.578 Authenticator - authState has been updated to signedIn
[DEBUG] 51:47.581 AuthClass - getting current credentials
[DEBUG] 51:47.582 Credentials - getting credentials
[DEBUG] 51:47.582 Credentials - picking up credentials
[DEBUG] 51:47.582 Credentials - getting new cred promise
[DEBUG] 51:47.582 Credentials - checking if credentials exists and not expired
[DEBUG] 51:47.583 Credentials - credentials not changed and not expired, directly return
[DEBUG] 51:47.583 AnalyticsClass - Analytics has been disabled
[DEBUG] 51:47.584 PubSub - subscribe options undefined
[DEBUG] 51:47.584 MqttOverWSProvider - Subscribing to topic(s) topic1
[DEBUG] 51:47.584 Credentials - getting credentials
[DEBUG] 51:47.584 Credentials - picking up credentials
[DEBUG] 51:47.584 Credentials - getting new cred promise
[DEBUG] 51:47.585 Credentials - checking if credentials exists and not expired
[DEBUG] 51:47.585 Credentials - are these credentials expired?
[DEBUG] 51:47.585 Credentials - credentials not changed and not expired, directly return
[DEBUG] 51:47.586 Signer {region: "ap-southeast-2", service: "iotdevicegateway"}
[DEBUG] 51:47.590 MqttOverWSProvider - Creating new MQTT client cca4e07f-a15a-46ce-904d-483a83162018
[WARN] 52:50.152 MqttOverWSProvider - cca4e07f-a15a-46ce-904d-483a83162018 {
  "errorCode": 7,
  "errorMessage": "AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.",
  "uri": "wss://a123456789d.iot.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/mqtt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAU7VGXF6UOWZIUFOM%2F20200502%2Fap-southeast-2%2Fiotdevicegateway%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20200502T055147Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=010d8..7dba&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQ..lk%3D"
}
ERROR: Disconnected, error code: 7
[DEBUG] 52:50.153 MqttOverWSProvider - Unsubscribing from topic(s) topic1
```

Any idea why I can't connect to the topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Who would have thought that a package was missing.

After installing

```
yarn add amazon-cognito-identity-js
```

everything worked fine on my physical iPhone.

I went to the **AWS IoT Core** page and *published* a test message from there and voilà I get the following object back

```
{
  "message": "Hello from AWS IoT console"
}
```

Comment: I got the error: `AMQJS0013E Invalid argument //wss://xxxxxid.iot.amazonaws.com/mqtt?...` in the console and couldn't find a solution to it. After adding the library as you suggested it worked.